# Why does a Where clause cause more data to be returned?

Tags: python, shareplum

I have a script that uses shareplum to get items from a very large and growing SharePoint (SP) list. Because of the size, I encountered the dreaded 5000 item limit set in SP. To get around that, I tried to page the data based on the 'ID' with a `Where` clause on the query.

```
# this is wrapped in a while.
# the idx is updated to the latest max if the results aren't empty.
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
idx = 0
query = {'Where': [('Gt', 'ID', str(idx))], 'OrderBy': ['ID']}
data = sp_list.GetListItems(view, query=query, row_limit=4750)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data[0:]))
```

That seemed to work but, after I added the `Where`, it started returning rows not visible on the SP web list. For example, the minimum ID on the web is, say, 500 while shareplum returns rows starting at 1. It also seems to be pulling in rows that are filtered out on the web. For example, it includes column values not included on the web. If the `Where` is removed, it brings back the exact list viewed on the web.

What is it that I'm getting wrong here? I'm brand new to shareplum; I looked at the docs but they don't go into much detail and all the examples are rather trivial.

Why does a Where clause cause more data to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seems shareplum will ignore any filters applied to the list to create the view when a `query` is provided to `GetListItems`. This is easily verified by removing the `query` param.

As a workaround, I'm now paging 'All Items' with a `row_limit` and `query` as below. This at least lets me get all the data and do any further filtering/grouping in python.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
idx = 0
more = True
while more:
    query = {'Where': [('Gt', 'ID', str(idx))]}
    # Page 'All Items' based on 'ID' > idx
    data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Items', query=query, row_limit=4500)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data[0:])
    if not data_df.empty:
        df = df.append(data_df)
        ids = pd.to_numeric(data_df['ID'])
        idx = ids.max()
    else:
        more = False
```

As to why shareplum behaves this way is still an open question.